# Add UMEKit Framework to Cocoa Application

Tags: cocoa, xcode, frameworks

I'm trying to link the [UMEKit Framework](http://parsekit.com/umekit/) into a cocoa application I'm working on. The application compiles fine but I cannot run the application due to the error:

dyld: Library not loaded: /Users/Joe/Library/Frameworks/UMEKit.framework/Versions/A/UMEKit
  Referenced from: /Users/Joe/Documents/[MY APP PATH]/Contents/MacOS/[APP NAME]
  Reason: image not found

I'm pretty sure it's a simple error brought about by me just not knowing how to properly link a framework in. I followed the apple documentation and added the framework project to my application project as a dependency but it just resulted in the same error.

I'd really appreciate some direct instructions on what exactly I need to do or what I appear to be missing here.

**EDIT:** This actually only happens when I compile and run as *debug*. For *release* it is fine. It would be useful to be able to use debug mode, of course, though so I don't know if this suggests anything to anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're not copying the framework into your app. You can verify this by selecting "Show Package Contents" from the app's context menu in the Finder and look if the framework is in the app (under Contents/Frameworks).

If not, you need to add a "Copy Files" build phase to your target. Bring up the inspector for the build phase in Xcode, select "Frameworks" as the destination, then drag your framework into the build phase.

Comment: Right had already done that and I've verified it is in the package as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I have again the same problem.... I have to manually copy the Aquatic Framework in systems/library/framwork... then it works.  Is there any other way to perform the task? And on e important thing, i am making plugins.. so is there any issue for adding frameworks in a plugin?